# Showing a Set is Inconsistent In Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Let $\Phi = \left \{ \alpha, \beta, \gamma \right \}$ be a set of three well-formed formulas. To show $\Phi$ is inconsistent, should I use deduction to show that $\Phi \vdash \phi$ for all $\phi \in \Phi$? If so, how would that look? Do I have to use all elements in $\Phi$ to deduce every $\phi \in \Phi$? If so, do I use axioms that include all three formulas or what? I apologize for my elementary understanding!

Comment: It sounds like you’re having trouble with the meaning of $\Phi\vdash \phi$ in general, so I would review the definition of proof from $\Phi$ carefully. No, you do not need to use all of the formulas in $\Phi.$ You can think of the $\Phi$ as extra assumptions you’re allowed to use, along with the logical axioms for your proof calculus.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay! I realize that now, thanks for also helping me understand it clearly too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Actual answer

First of all, no, there's no obligation to use everything in $\Phi$. The set $\Phi$ is the set of sentences you're *allowed* to use in a proof. Adding stuff to $\Phi$ only makes it easier to prove things.

You're also mixing up $\Phi$ and the set of all sentences in the language. Obviously $\Phi$ proves every sentence in $\Phi$. What you want to talk about is the *sentences in general* which $\Phi$ proves.

Now, on to the issue of inconsistency. There are two notions of inconsistency of a set of sentences $\Phi$:

- $\Phi$ proves **everything**.
- For some $p$, $\Phi$ proves both $p$ and $\neg p$.

Conveniently, in classical propositional logic these are equivalent: clearly if $\Phi$ is inconsistent in the first sense, it's inconsistent in the second sense, and conversely if $\Phi$ proves both $p$ and $\neg p$ we can use proof by contradiction to prove whatever we want from $\Phi$: "Suppose $\neg q$. Then ... we conclude $p$ and $\neg p$. So since we got a contradiction from $\neg q$, we have $q$."

So all you need to do is find a *single* sentence such that $\Phi$ proves both the sentence and its negation.

---

### Irrelevant but interesting note

Now note that I said "classical logic" above. There are other logics out there, and in some of them it is *not* the case that proving a contradiction means proving everything. For such logics we do need to distinguish between the notions of inconsistency given above: generally, the second (weaker) one is called "inconsistent" while the first is called "trivial." In these logics, and unlike classical logic, *inconsistent theories may be interesting*; see e.g. [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply and give me a helpful answer. So what you're saying is that we try to find a formula in $\Phi$ such that that formula proves another formula in $\Phi$ and its negation?

Comment: @numericalorange No, the formulas in question don't have to be in $\Phi$. Just find some formula $p$ - in $\Phi$ or not in $\Phi$ - such that $\Phi$ proves $p$ and $\Phi$ proves $\neg p$. For example, if $\Phi=\{a, a\rightarrow b, \neg b\vee\neg b, c\}$ then we can take $p=b$: we have $\Phi\vdash b$ (by modus ponens: $a$ and $a\rightarrow b$ gives us $b$) but we also have $\Phi\vdash\neg b$ (reasoning by cases, $\neg b\vee\neg b$ gives us $b$). So this $\Phi$ is inconsistent. Note that we never used $c$; that's fine. Does that example help?

Comment: Wow, that example really clears up everything! Thanks for your time and help, I truly understand what to do now. :)

Comment: @numericalorange Glad to help!

Comment: Note that the two notions of consistency are equivalent in intuitionistic logic.  I don't know of a name for logics where the two notions are equivalent.